# Firebird UTF-8 storage issue in a VarChar field

Tags: utf-8, firebird2.1

I am have been having problems storing UTF-8 characters in a Firebird 2.1 DB Varchar field.

The field definition does not have a character set specified. The character set is always passed in the connection string.

The character set on all fields is set as NONE. Connection string is

```xml
<add name="ConnectionString" 
  connectionString="character set=UTF8;initial catalog=&quot;c:\temp\data.FDB&quot;;user id=SYSDBA;password=;connection lifetime=15;pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;data source=localhost"
  providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
```

The .NET driver version is 2.1.0.0. Firebird itself is version 2.1.3.18185.

It was my understanding that this would override any setting on the field itself however I have been having trouble storing characters e.g. Right single quote (ALT + 0146) in the database. It always comes out as an strange question mark character.

After a few days of blaming the ASP.NET web site, I discovered that if I set the character set as UTF-8 on the field (domain) itself, then it appears to fix the problem.

Is this correct?

I always thought that passing the character set in the connection string would do the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure the field doesn't have a character set (ie is it `null` or `NONE`)? When you don't specify a character set for a column, but the database itself has a default character set, then the field inherits that character set (as it was set at column creation time). This may lead to other character set conversions than you expect. Could you also specify which driver you are using (+ version), and the connection string you use?

Comment: The character set on all fields is set as NONE.  Connection string is **<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="character set=UTF8;initial catalog=&quot;c:\temp\data.FDB&quot;;user id=SYSDBA;password=;connection lifetime=15;pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;data source=localhost" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />** The .NET driver version is 2.1.0.0. Firebird itself is version 2.1.3.18185.

Comment: I have added that info to the question as it is better for readability. I'll check what the Firebird .net provider exactly does in this case, might take a few days.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In the meantime, I am looking going to see if removing the character set from the connection string helps and look at FBClone to see how easy it would be to set the database char set to UTF8.

Comment: Setting Charset=None everywhere appears to have fixed the problem without having to clone the database and set it to UTF-8. The ASP.NET web site is set for encoding to be UTF-8. Am I correct in thinking that with the Firebird Charset set to None this means that it will store the data in whatever format is passed into it?

Comment: Yes, but it is really a dangerous default to use. I'd strongly suggest you alter your database to explicitly use UTF-8 and also the UTF8 connection character set. I am not sure why specifying UTF8 as the character set doesn't work for you though.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of altering the default character set without using fbclone. I was hoping that it would be possible with an alter table statement.